# Why is the main() function always an int and not a long?

Tags: c++

I was recently coding in C++ when I realized that the `int main()` function works fine as a `long main()` and can support larger numbers (up to 2^63) so why is that not the normal way it is coded?

Comment: That's by definition the signature of an executable entry point, and supported by a variety of OS like this. If you want to get program output of any kind, use output streams.

Comment: Do you really need more than 2^32 different return codes? Normally you return EXIT_SUCCESS or EXIT_FAILURE indicating to the calling process success or failure

Comment: And even `int` is already too much for some OS. Typically, on those OS, you can only use error code from 0 to 255, so a single `uint8_t`.